# "Unexpected token: punc ())" when building for production

Tags: angular, eslint

If I try to test-build my application with `ng build --prod --aot` I get the following, quite short, error message:

```
$ ng build --prod
                                                                                         
Date: 2019-01-26T17:26:45.018Z
Hash: 979690c7a363996f24b8
Time: 28274ms
chunk {0} runtime.ea8176a0aa687d0c7546.js (runtime) 2.23 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} common.78f3e0cd7d0f774768aa.js (common) 583 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {2} main.5f97cda0f273b510e26a.js (main) 973 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.c2a7344c1c84ba3d2a73.js (polyfills) 58.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.1094b1dd78a0fa2c8fa7.css (styles) 85 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.92565e561816566c4426.js () 3.74 MB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6.a4ec6e690b75a22ddb72.js () 6.3 kB  [rendered]

ERROR in 5.92565e561816566c4426.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc ()) [5.92565e561816566c4426.js:25865,4]
```

No idea what's causing this. How can I fix this? Last time I checked this worked.

I have already tried `rm -rf node_modules/`.

---

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "mz-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.12.0",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@ngx-share/button": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/braintree-web": "^3.6.4",
    "angular-mentions": "^0.8.0",
    "braintree-web": "^3.41.0",
    "braintree-web-drop-in": "^1.14.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-logger": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^4.5.0",
    "paypal-checkout": "^4.0.239",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "quill-mention": "git+https://github.com/silentsnooc/quill-mention.git",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.1.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.10",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.0",
    "express-http-proxy": "^1.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

**Part of the build log**

```
[1m[33mWARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping unused variable template [6.a4ec6e690b75a22ddb72.js:136,12][39m[22m

[1m[33mWARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping unused variable routes [6.a4ec6e690b75a22ddb72.js:148,4][39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in 5.92565e561816566c4426.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc ()) [5.92565e561816566c4426.js:25865,4][39m[22m
Child [1mmini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??extracted!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!src/styles.scss[39m[22m:
                   [1mAsset[39m[22m     [1mSize[39m[22m  [1mChunks[39m[22m  [1m[39m[22m[1m[39m[22m[1mChunk Names[39m[22m
    [1m[32m3rdpartylicenses.txt[39m[22m  1 bytes        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[39m[22m
    Entrypoint [1mmini-css-extract-plugin[39m[22m = [1m[32m*[39m[22m
    chunk    {[1m[33m0[39m[22m} [1m[32m*[39m[22m (mini-css-extract-plugin) 102 KiB[1m[33m [entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m
Child [1mmini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??extracted!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!src/theme.scss[39m[22m:
                   [1mAsset[39m[22m     [1mSize[39m[22m  [1mChunks[39m[22m  [1m[39m[22m[1m[39m[22m[1mChunk Names[39m[22m
    [1m[32m3rdpartylicenses.txt[39m[22m  1 bytes        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[39m[22m
    Entrypoint [1mmini-css-extract-plugin[39m[22m = [1m[32m*[39m[22m
    chunk    {[1m[33m0[39m[22m} [1m[32m*[39m[22m (mini-css-extract-plugin) 55.6 KiB[1m[33m [entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m

WARNING in Terser Plugin: global_defs ngDevMode redefined [main.5f97cda0f273b510e26a.js:14309,21]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: global_defs ngDevMode redefined [main.5f97cda0f273b510e26a.js:14510,25]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: global_defs ngDevMode redefined [main.5f97cda0f273b510e26a.js:15652,21]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: global_defs ngDevMode redefined [main.5f97cda0f273b510e26a.js:15658,21]
```

---

With `--source-map`

```
$ ng build --prod --aot --source-map 
                                                                                                               
Date: 2019-01-26T22:31:44.106Z
Hash: 51afc4cc158a10e520c6
Time: 45390ms
chunk {0} runtime.b29d49d6f279fff34f57.js, runtime.b29d49d6f279fff34f57.js.map (runtime) 2.29 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} common.70409de1782336a79716.js, common.70409de1782336a79716.js.map (common) 639 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {2} main.01e8ea6a2dd33c4e19d8.js, main.01e8ea6a2dd33c4e19d8.js.map (main) 970 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.22294cd4941de9604b91.js, polyfills.22294cd4941de9604b91.js.map (polyfills) 61.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.97ca4c55e9ba593fdf4c.css, styles.97ca4c55e9ba593fdf4c.css.map (styles) 85.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.33da963a3dd6decc5efc.js, 5.33da963a3dd6decc5efc.js.map () 1.9 MB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6.85bd192b02e86745d878.js, 6.85bd192b02e86745d878.js.map () 6.35 kB  [rendered]
```

Without `--source-map`

```
$ ng build --prod --aot 
                                                                                         
Date: 2019-01-26T22:32:18.173Z
Hash: b5bcaa2123bb6718baf2
Time: 28403ms
chunk {0} runtime.0935b498984fda7c2e4f.js (runtime) 2.23 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} common.78f3e0cd7d0f774768aa.js (common) 583 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {2} main.2ae834dcaf8208d7aecd.js (main) 970 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.588b345e325a2549098e.js (polyfills) 61.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.088d5b7a7a0995d1df55.css (styles) 85.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.7e99fa00323b77c4e1c2.js () 3.82 MB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6.954a4978d0c6c411bb2f.js () 6.3 kB  [rendered]

ERROR in 5.7e99fa00323b77c4e1c2.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc ()) [5.7e99fa00323b77c4e1c2.js:27338,4]
```

With `--source-map --named-chunks`

```
$ ng build --prod --source-map --named-chunks
                                                                                                                        
Date: 2019-01-26T23:00:18.699Z
Hash: c37b8f2ccfedbbf077fa
Time: 61888ms
chunk {0} runtime.a670ad696846ba781d64.js, runtime.a670ad696846ba781d64.js.map (runtime) 2.37 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} common.d7fbf062c6d87ac4ade2.js, common.d7fbf062c6d87ac4ade2.js.map (common) 639 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {2} component-application-application-module-ngfactory.22de247f215039a3cf63.js, component-application-application-module-ngfactory.22de247f215039a3cf63.js.map (component-application-application-module-ngfactory) 1.9 MB  [rendered]
chunk {3} main.2897da054822ebda9646.js, main.2897da054822ebda9646.js.map (main) 973 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} module-embedding-calendar-calendar-module-ngfactory.5b0025d2f887a5d7b22d.js, module-embedding-calendar-calendar-module-ngfactory.5b0025d2f887a5d7b22d.js.map (module-embedding-calendar-calendar-module-ngfactory) 6.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} polyfills.04ae14cfab6dbb09ad49.js, polyfills.04ae14cfab6dbb09ad49.js.map (polyfills) 61.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {6} styles.52c1571339895f2464fa.css, styles.52c1571339895f2464fa.css.map (styles) 85.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

It seems that

```
ng build --prod --named-chunks --verbose --build-optimizer=false --source-map
```

finally does the trick - with this, I am finally getting the source of the error:

```
ERROR in component-application-application-module-ngfactory.7eb30a010bb7783ce652.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc ()) [./node_modules/quill-mention/src/quill.mention.js:183,0][component-application-application-module-ngfactory.7eb30a010bb7783ce652.js:29528,4]
```

Comment: Hard to tell with the little information that you added to your question.

Comment: Add your package.json details. You mention that "this worked" the last time that you checked. What do you mean by "last time"? A previous angular version? a previous CLI version?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Fair enough. I added the package.json file as well as the verbose output from the `ng build`. It looks like it has something to do with scss?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo By last time I meant before I added the `quill` editor to my project. Just merged a fork into my master and now I can't build it anymore - I would not really know what could cause this. No major version updates as far as I can remember.

Comment: Would you mind adding the output of `ng build --prod --aot --source-map --verbose`? See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5741#issuecomment-444580484

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks for that hint. I've posted a link to the output - it's quite large. I could not see an error there though.

Comment: Could you update the gist with the output of `ng build --prod --aot --source-map`? verbose was just to much garbage output

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Okay, It's getting weirder. I have added the output - one for each scenario with/without `--source-map`. I am not getting the error if `--source-map` is added.

Comment: Its interesting to see the difference in size of the 5. chunk with --sm (1.9mb) and withouth it (3.8mb, basically double). You might want to use the `--named-chunks` flag in order to identify the problematic module (Im assuming that the last chunks are lazy modules or similar)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo True, didn't notice the difference in file size. I have added `--named-chunks` - Given the output, and looking at the file size, the module seems to be `component-application-application-module` which is actually the main module - not sure if that helps a lot to locate the error :/

Comment: Indeed. Yup its kinda hard to truly be helpful without a repro of your problem. You might want to open an issue in the cli repro, linking the old one that I posted in the comments and this question, but in order to get some attention you will have to provide a repro....

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Especially since i't building *with* source maps but not without .. no idea how I can make this reproducible..

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Ok I think I am on it. I have added `--build-optimizer=false` so the command is `ng build --prod --named-chunks --verbose --output-path tmp/ --build-optimizer=false --source-map` - this points me to the source file finally. It seems that I am also linking to the `src/` directory of the `quill-mention` module.

Comment: If you are unable to provide a repro, the best next thing would be to provide the logs for both `ng build  --named-chunks --prod--aot --source-map --verbose` and `ng build --named-chunks --prod --aot  --verbose`. The latest might provide some more detailed information

Comment: Seems like your own fork is messing with you? :D

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Indeed - I found the issue. It was a "missing comma" (according to ESLint) which I put there to get rid of the warning (in WebStorm) and well - you know the rest of the story .. ^^ Thank you for helping me - this would've taken me much longer if it wasn't for your help! :D

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It all started with this warning:

[image]

It was this missing comma, which I put there to silence the warning, which rendered my project uncompileable.

I was only able to locate this issue by using `--source-map` but also setting `--build-optimizer=false`

```
ng build --prod --named-chunks --verbose --build-optimizer=false --source-map
```

Comment: Nice! Solved here by removing all instances of "?." in the code

Comment: How can I find such an issue?

Answer (score 33):

I downgraded from Angular 15 to Angular 14 and need to re-align `ES2022` -> `es2020`.

`tsconfig.json`

```
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
```

Comment: I did not find this in the `angular.json` file but in `tsconfig.json`. So if you didn't find it in `angular.json`, look there, too.

Answer (score 13):

After upgrading to angular 8 during production build, I was getting "Error in common-es2015.xxx.js from Terser Unexpected token: Punc(;) [common-es2015.xxx.js] "

After setting sourceMap to true in angular.json file - configurations- production section, compiler displayed actual file name with error line number. It was due to an extra semicolon in a variable declaration in the class file.

```
putGamma: any = 0.0;;
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! That was exactly my issue as well. Any idea why this would fail the build now?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was a **leftover** comma at the end of a list of functions inside a custom .js file in `\src` directory.

The tip of by `--source-map=true` and also setting `--build-optimizer=false` in `angular.json` helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

After downgrade from angular 15 to angular 14 i received same error and i fix it changing es2022 to es2020 in esconfig.ts

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out it was caused by https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parameter-append

There was an extra comma after a list of parameters in a function call

I removed the comma in my own copy of url-parameter-append.js and then it worked.

I reported the bug to the author of that package https://github.com/techinity/url-parameter-append/issues/10 , but really IMO the bug is

- in the way angular build reports errors
- in "Terser": an extra comma after a list of parameters is legit in js/ts.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by using ES6 in a `.js` file in a TypeScript Angular project. Refactoring the `.js` file's code to ES5 fixed the problem. I used `ng build --prod --aot` to check if the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false
        },
 }
```

**buildOptimizer** and **optimization** was not present in my package.json for production. So, I guess their default values are true. Adding them and setting them to "false" solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me an error on my local machine but not on the build server. In my case my packages were outdated. So I did NPM I again and after that everything worked back as normal.