# ng build --prod throws Unexpected token: punc ()) because of imported library in the module list

Tags: angular

The app loads fine with `ng serve` but throws `Unexpected token: punc ())` while building with `ng build --prod`. Build the app with source map and found the reason which is caused by [angular-gauge-chart](https://github.com/recogizer/angular-gauge-chart). Asked the library developers for help and this is what they said:

> @maihannijat it is a library, not an angular app. We use ng serve
>   command to run an app that hosts a dev environment for the library.
>   The library can be built using usual ng build angular-gauge-chart
>   command.

I imported the module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [XYZ],
  imports: [
    ...
    GaugeChartModule,
  ]
})
```

And used in the component template:

```
<rg-gauge-chart [canvasWidth]="canvasWidth"
                [needleValue]="needleValue"
                [centralLabel]="centralLabel"
                [options]="options"
                [name]="name"
                [bottomLabel]="bottomLabel">
</rg-gauge-chart>
```

I did exactly their guide says here:
https://github.com/recogizer/angular-gauge-chart

I tried to import library in the component as:

```
import 'angular-gauge-chart';
```

And removed from the modules but it throws binding errors and asks for `GaugeChartModule` to be imorted in the modules.

**Edit:**

Debug with:

```
ng build --prod --named-chunks --verbose --build-optimizer=false --source-map
```

Error:

> Unexpected token: punc ())
>   [./node_modules/gauge-chart/dist/bundle.js:169,0]

```
.attr(
  'transform',
  'translate(' + (n + 2 * e) + ', ' + (n + e) + ')',
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fixed in `angular-gauge-chart@0.7.2`. Thank you again for pointing this out.

For those who will ever face the same problem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383809) helped me to find the problem. In my case, the problem was in one of dependencies that didn't have proper `bundle.js` file. My `prettier` was configured in such way that it formatted already built bundle. Thus, some commas and other important information was lost.

Answer (score 1):

The version `0.7.1` throws error because of trailing commas. I am using version `0.6.0` now until the developers fix the problem in the new version.

Reference: https://github.com/recogizer/angular-gauge-chart/issues/28

Answer (score -1):

import *  as angularGaugeChart from 'angular-gauge-chart';

Comment: Please, never answer if didn't carefully read the question. The question is much-much deeper and well-described than the answer you suggest.